# addEventListener in loop, why do I need to create a function that returns a function?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to do a quite simple stuff: add a listener on a code loop that basically refers to the loop index.

After some searching, I came up with a solution, but I don't understand why the other version does not work.

Here is the javascript code (that you can load from any empty html page):

```
var myarray = ["House", "Car", "Fruit"];
for(var i=0; i<myarray.length; i++)
{
    // Code that create the div
    var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
    mydiv.innerHTML = myarray[i];
    document.body.appendChild(mydiv);

    // Add listener
    // Version 1: create a new variable that points to i
    var tmp_i = i;
    mydiv.addEventListener("click", function(){alert("Version 1: You clicked on div nb " + tmp_i)}, false);
    // ==> Problem: always output the maximum value of i !!!

    // Version 2: create a function that outputs a function (a bit crazy)
    var my_function_creator = function(arg_i) {
        return function(){alert("Version 2: You clicked on div nb " + arg_i)};
    };
    mydiv.addEventListener("click", my_function_creator(i), false);
    // This works !
}
```

So here is my question: why the first version does not work, while the second one works ? For me the `tmp_i` is a fresh copy of i, and therefore it should not be modified... And is the second method the best way to proceed ?

Thanks !

Comment: See the linked question's answers. The first one doesn't work because all of the handlers see the **same** `tmp_i` variable, and so naturally see the last value it was assigned. In the second one, there's a **different** `arg_i` for each call to `my_function_creator` whose value is never changed.

Comment: If you want the first version to work, use `let tmp_i = i;`

Comment: this is because in the first version you are referring at the wrong object and this is caused by javascript hoisting, take a look at this example http://ignaciothayer.com/post/a-dangerous-example-of-javascript-hoisting/